# Material-UI theming does not apply with yarn pnp (berry)

Tags: material-ui, yarnpkg

Spent lots of time on this issue but I can't find a different reason.

When using yarn (v1) with Plug and Play or yarn v2. (berry) I can't get
Material-UI theming v 4.4.3 working.

Here's the example below.  There is no problem when using a standard non pnp yarn configuration.

(create-react-app)

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiButton: { variant: "outlined" }
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <Button>text</Button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.4.3",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The theme is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a double initiation of @material-ui/styles problem. Guys from @material-ui team seem to be fixing this at the moment.

importing MuiThemeProvider as ThemeProvider from @material-ui/core/styles instead of importing ThemeProvider from @material-ui/styles fixed the issue.

I also ommited @material-ui/styles in my package.json

Hope this helps someone ...